# Session Won't Stay on Redirection

Tags: php, session, set, session-variables

Here's the code:

```
final public function login($email) {
    $this->email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $this->q = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE mail = '$this->email'"; 
    $this->r = mysql_query($this->q);
    $this->id = mysql_result($this->r, 0);
    $_SESSION['id'] = "$this->id";

    header('Location: me.php');
    exit;
    }
```

I'm not sure when I redirect the session does not stay.  I've echoed it on the current page and it showed.  Any solutions?  I have a global namespace so the session is set in all files.

Comment: Have you started the session using `session_start`?

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` on this page and _every_ other page where `$_SESSION` is accessed?

Comment: `$_SESSION['id'] = "$this->id"`? Please no... also, why are you making everything an instance variable? Is there a good reason for this, or is this trying to be OOP?

Comment: Try using `window.location()` Javascript function instead of using `header()`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're dealing with Sessions in PHP, you should use `session_start()` to load session data into memory.

Call `session_start()` only once per you page.